# conditional operator mixing a wrapped type and constant integer expression

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I am getting things I don't expect in C#, when I combine as second and third operands of a conditional operator a narrower nullable and a wider numeric value. This DOES NOT WORK, but I find it does if the wider numeric value is a constant expression of type int and the narrower nullable is of type SByte? or Int16?. Demo:

```
bool test = true;
Int16? aShort = 5;
Int32 anInt = 5;
const Int32 aConstInt = 4;
Object o1 = test ? aShort : anInt;      // does not compile
Object o2 = test ? aShort : aConstInt;  // does compile
```

My question is why does it compile if my int is a constant? And I can't find reference to this in the C# language specification, what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the C# 4.0 language specification, §7.14 (Conditional operator) states the following:

> The second and third operands, `x` and `y`, of the `?:` operator control the type of the conditional expression.
>
> If `x` has type `X` and `y` has type `Y` then
>
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `X` to `Y`, but not from `Y` to `X`, then `Y` is the type of the conditional expression.
> - If an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from `Y` to `X`, but not from `X` to `Y`, then `X` is the type of the conditional expression.
> - Otherwise, no expression type can be determined, and a compile-time error occurs.

And §6.1.9 (Implicit constant expression conversions) states the following:

> An implicit constant expression conversion permits the following conversions:
>
> - A *constant-expression* (§7.19) of type `int` can be converted to type `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`, provided the value of the *constant-expression* is within the range of the destination type.
> - A *constant-expression* of type `long` can be converted to type `ulong`, provided the value of the *constant-expression* is not negative.

As you can see, constant expressions of type `int` and `long` are treated specially.

Thus the expression `test ? aShort : aConstInt` is valid because there is an implicit conversion from the `int` constant expression `4` to `short` and then to `short?` (and thus the type of the expression is `short?`), but `test ? aShort : anInt` is not valid because there is neither an implicit conversion from a non-constant expression of type `int` to `short?` nor from `short?` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
const Int32 aConstInt = 4;
Object o2 = test ? aShort : aConstInt;  // does compile
```

The compiler is able to treat the `aConstInt` reference in the second line as if you had simply put a `4` there.  Based on the context, it turns the `4` into a `short`, not an `Int32`.  The compiler behaves differently if it only knows that the input is an `Int32`, as is the case when it's not a `const`.

If you had declared:

```
const Int32 aConstInt = short.MaxValue + 1;
```

Then the compiler will not allow the same line to compile:

```
Object o2 = test ? aShort : aConstInt;  // does not compile
```

Because it's now treating it as `32768`, which isn't a `short`.

Comment: That's good, but not good enough. I can get a constant expression of type short by writing const short aConstShort = 4; if I declare an sbyte? with sbyte? anSByte = 4;, and then try to combine these I get an error! It is *specifically* the const Int32 that is being allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first conditional doesn't compile is not because of the `const`; the issue is with the data types. `aShort` is a `Nullable<Int16>`, if you declared it as a normal `Int16` it would work just fine

```
Int16 aShort = 5; // not nullable
Int32 anInt = 5;
Object o1 = test ? aShort : anInt;      // does compile
```

When you have `? (short?) : (int)`, it's not able to do the conversion because the compiler doesn't know how to convert the `(short?)` to an `int`.

When you have `? (short) : (int)`, the *run time* is converting the `short` to an `int` to fit the larger data type.

However the second conditional *does* compile thanks to some special magic the C# *compiler* uses when handling `const` integers. When you have `? (short?) : (const int = 4)`, the compiler is treating the `const int` as a `short` because you've declared it as a value that will fit into a `short` data type. The `short` is then implicitly converted to a `short?` in the result.

If you had `? (short) : (const int = 4)` it behaves just like the first case, up-converting the `short` to an `int` at run-time.

If you had `? (short?) : (short?)` works because the compiler knows how to implicitly convert a `short` to a `short?`.

If you look at the result types at runtime you can actually see this.

```
Int16 aShort1 = 5; // not nullable
Int16? aShort2 = 5; // nullable
object o1 = test ? aShort1 : anInt;
object o2 = test ? aShort2 : aConstInt;
object o3 = test ? aShort1 : aConstInt;
object o4 = test ? aShort1 : aShort2;

o1.GetType() // System.Int32
o2.GetType() // System.Int16
o3.GetType() // System.Int32
o4.GetType() // System.Int16
```

In fact if you look at the generated IL for `o2` you will see this:

```
IL_001E:  ldarg.0     
IL_001F:  ldfld       UserQuery.test
IL_0024:  brtrue.s    IL_002E
IL_0026:  ldc.i4.4    // your integer constant
IL_0027:  newobj      System.Nullable<System.Int16>..ctor // Notice the type here
IL_002C:  br.s        IL_0034
IL_002E:  ldarg.0     
IL_002F:  ldfld       UserQuery.aShort2
IL_0034:  nop         
IL_0035:  box         System.Nullable<System.Int16>
IL_003A:  stloc.1     // o2
```

Comment: OK, but why it compiles with `const Int32` when there is still `Nullable<Int16>`?

Comment: p.s.w.g could you please delete your answer? it is not adding anything to this discussion.

Comment: @Mishax I disagree. I think that my point about the result types at run-time is relevant. I've added more examples to illustrate the point.

Comment: p.s.w.g You wrote "some special magic"?  Secondly, the short? and short go to short?, not short! You can't rely on .GetType() to tell if your result is Nullable or not.

Comment: @Mishax I've specified exactly what that "magic" is by including the IL. about the last point, yes you're right there, I had it backwards in my mind when I was writing this up.

Answer (score 0):

The C# compiler treats constants specially. This special property propagates even across expressions like `1+2`. `null` and lambdas are also special: they don't have a CLR type yet you can convert them to any reference type or to any matching delegate type. (`null` is *not* of type object!).

This is mandated by the C# spec. It forces implementations to resolve constant expressions and maintain their convertibility properties.

Example:

```
short x = 1; //assigning an integer literal to a short - works because it is a constant
short y = 1+2; //also works for expressions
```

You can also assign a long to an int without a cast:

```
const Int64 a = 1;
Int32 b = a;
```

The constants just propagate.

Comment: This is not answering the question. I am aware of the difference between const and non-const expressions. I am puzzled about the behavior specifically of const int expressions.

Comment: Well, your const int is a compile-time constant so the same rules apply. Don't you think? I reviewed this again - is there behavior not explained by my answer?

Comment: I think you might be right, that the same rules do apply. But you haven't said which rule that is. Which rule would allow a const int to be compared with a nullable short, but not allow a const short to be compared with a nullable sbyte?